# JavaScript slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a slider, but i have run in to a problem: `slideWidth` variable (which is the width of the slide) is always the same, so when it gets to the second slide it doesn't want to go further, similar with the previous slide it slides to the empty space because of the fixed variable value. + It doesn't want to animate.
**How to fix this?**

Please check out the code:

```js
// Slider
const slider_wrapp = document.querySelector('.tract-slider');
const slider = document.querySelector('.tract-slider-wrapp');
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('tract-slide');

const leftBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-left');
const rightBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-right');

let swWidth = slider_wrapp.clientWidth;
let sliderWidth = swWidth * slide.length;
let slideWidth = swWidth;

slider.style.width = sliderWidth + "px";

for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
  slide.item(i).style.width = " " + swWidth + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  slider.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-slideWidth) + "px)";
}

function moveLeft() {
  slider.style.transform = "translateX(" + (slideWidth) + "px)";
}

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveRight()
});

leftBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveLeft();
});
```

```css
.tract-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tract-slider-wrapp {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: translate 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
  -o-transition: translate 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
  transition: translate 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
}

.tract-slide {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/126282/pexels-photo-126282.jpeg");
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/29017/pexels-photo-29017.jpg");
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/70760/dandelion-dandelion-seeds-taraxacum-fluffy-70760.jpeg");
}

.tract-slider-control {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.tract-slider-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.tract-slider-btn:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tract-slider">
  <div class="tract-slider-wrapp">
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tract-slider-control">
    <div class="tract-slider-btn slide-left">Prev</div>
    <div class="tract-slider-btn slide-right">Next</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> P.S. If you know the solution please write it in JavaScript not JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you missed to calculate the `translateX` position of your slideWrapper : (the `slideWidth` var )

to fix it you have to check and assign a new calculated value instead of setting it always to the slider width .

Note that I've added calculation in both `moveRight()` and `moveLeft()`

See below working snippet : (using only js)

```js
// Slider
const slider_wrapp = document.querySelector('.tract-slider');
const slider = document.querySelector('.tract-slider-wrapp');
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('tract-slide');

const leftBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-left');
const rightBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-right');

let swWidth = slider_wrapp.clientWidth;
let sliderWidth = swWidth * slide.length;
let slideWidth = 0;

slider.style.width = sliderWidth + "px";

for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
  slide.item(i).style.width = " " + swWidth + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  slideWidth === sliderWidth - swWidth ? slideWidth = 0 : slideWidth += swWidth;
  slider.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-slideWidth) + "px)";
}

function moveLeft() {  
  slideWidth === 0 ? slideWidth = sliderWidth-swWidth :  slideWidth -= swWidth;
  slider.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-slideWidth) + "px)";
}

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveRight()
});

leftBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveLeft();
});
```

```css
.tract-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tract-slider-wrapp {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
  -o-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
  transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(.08, .13, 0, .81);
}

.tract-slide {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/126282/pexels-photo-126282.jpeg");
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/29017/pexels-photo-29017.jpg");
}

.tract-slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/70760/dandelion-dandelion-seeds-taraxacum-fluffy-70760.jpeg");
}

.tract-slider-control {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.tract-slider-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.tract-slider-btn:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tract-slider">
  <div class="tract-slider-wrapp">
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
    <div class="tract-slide"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tract-slider-control">
    <div class="tract-slider-btn slide-left">Prev</div>
    <div class="tract-slider-btn slide-right">Next</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much, only one more thing, what could I do to make it animate?

Comment: Ohh, I used translate in my css transition property instead of transform, its ok now... :)

Comment: Sorry to bother again, do you maybe know how to fix it so it doesnt jump to first slide after i click next on the third, but to animate from right to left just as if it would be the next slide after third one. I think it could be done using appendChild and insertBefore but i couldnt figure it out.

Comment: I'll see how to workround this , I' think all the solution could change !

Comment: so sorry , just tried to fix it using translate but its seem little bit tricky , Gotcha lot of time , i'll look after this when i'll have more time :)